# How to read numbers (separated by spaces) into an array?

Tags: c++

How to read numbers (separated by spaces) into an array?

Input (getline):
100 231 144 123 551

```
tab[0] = 100;
tab[1] = 231;
```

...

How I can do this ?

Comment: You most like want to split the string and then do the assigment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::cin >> i` breaks on whitespace by default. If you want to handle things on a per-line basis, you could use a `std::istringstream`.

If the line is mutable, you can just replace spaces with zeros, counting elements on the way if you want a single correct allocation, and use `atoi` on a second pass..

Answer (score 1):

The stupid way is to read the string byte-by-byte and do the translation yourself.

Or you can use `sscanf`:

`char input[] = "100 231 144 123 551"

sscanf(input, "%d%d%d%d%d", tab[0], tab[1], tab[2], tab[3], tab[4]);`

But I guess you are actually using `getline` of an `istream` object - if this is the case, you may just use the operator `>>` instead:

if it is the standard input stream `cin`:

`cin>>tab[0]>>tab[1]>>...`

or, if it is a file stream `fin`:

`fin>>tab[0]>>tab[1]>>...`

In the above, I always suppose that you know the number of numbers in the array. If you don't, then you should have something as symbol of termination - then basically you just read numbers until encounter the symbol. It will then depend on what exactly is the symbol.

Comment: Stupid solution. I don't know how much will the numbers.

Comment: Way to treat the guy that spends his time giving you the most detailed answer. By the way you said "array", which has static size. So you absolutely *do* know how many numbers to scan.